# 'hg pull' failing in CruiseControl.NET build because no changes were detected

Tags: mercurial, cruisecontrol.net

I have CruiseControl.NET configured using the Mercurial source control block. When I first executed the build, the code was downloaded from my Kiln repository and the build went off without a hitch. However, every subsequent build fails, and I believe the reason is because *hg.exe pull* is returning an "error" code of 1 indicating there were no changes detected. I verified the return code by using Process Explorer. The thing is, CruiseControl.NET is apparently treating this as a failure condition but I'd prefer if it simply did not treat the attempt as a build. It's been my experience that with other source control systems, CruiseControl.NET will simply do nothing if there are no changes in the repository.

```
[Project:DEBUG] Starting process [C:\Program Files\Mercurial\hg.exe] in working directory [D:\Working] with arguments [pull https://urlredacted]
[Project:DEBUG] Not setting PriorityClass on [C:\Program Files\Mercurial\hg.exe] to default Normal
[10:DEBUG] [Project C:\Program Files\Mercurial\hg.exe] standard-error stream closed -- null received in event
[9:DEBUG] [Project C:\Program Files\Mercurial\hg.exe] pulling from https://urlredacted
[6:DEBUG] [Project C:\Program Files\Mercurial\hg.exe] process exited event received
[9:DEBUG] [Project C:\Program Files\Mercurial\hg.exe] searching for changes
[9:DEBUG] [Project C:\Program Files\Mercurial\hg.exe] no changes found
[9:DEBUG] [Project C:\Program Files\Mercurial\hg.exe] standard-output stream closed -- null received in event
[Project:WARN] Source control failure (GetModifications): Source control operation failed: . Process command: C:\Program Files\Mercurial\hg.exe pull https://urlredacted
```

My question is, is there a CruiseControl.NET configuration I can use to get it to ignore the build attempt if *hg.exe pull* results in a 1, or am I going to have to go modify CruiseControl.NET code?

I'm using CruiseControl.NET 1.6 and Mercurial 2.1.

Comment: Ok, the issue here was that I was forcing a build from CCTray. The Mercurial code in CruiseControl.NET apparently doesn't ignore the result from *hg.exe pull* when the build is forced. My solution was to write a batch file that acts as a pass-through to hg.exe and resets the errorlevel if necessary. Then, I changed my CruiseControl.NET script, specifying the batch file instead of hg.exe directly:

    @echo off
    "C:\Program Files\Mercurial\hg.exe" %*
    if errorlevel 1 set errorlevel=0

Comment: Nathan: it would be great if you could add the comment as a real answer — it's okay to answer your own question!

Comment: Nathan - doesn't that hide real errors? ie - "or an update had unresolved files." (from the help)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that Mercurial 2.1 changed the [return code for `hg pull`](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/UpgradeNotes) when no changesets were pulled. That is a backwards incompatible change and scripts and tools will now have to be updated to take this into account.

I expect the next version of CruiseControl.NET to take this into account. In the mean time, a small batch file can be used (as you suggest in your comment).